# Line chart from React Apex Chart returns [object Object] in custom tooltip

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, linechart, apexcharts

I'm displaying a line chart using [React Apex Chart](https://apexcharts.com/docs/react-charts/).

I have to change the default tooltip display from the chart as shown in the first image below.

But when I tried to change the tooltip display by following [this documentation](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/tooltip/), I got `[object Object]` returned from the tooltip as seen in the second image below.

So **my questions** are what's the code for:

1. changing the tooltip display for the selected Y value (upper orange arrow)
2. and remove the tooltip display for the X-axis (bottom orange arrow)?

**Design:**

[image: design]

**Actual image:**

[image: actual]

Here is the code:

Chart.js

```js
import React from 'react'

import ReactApexChart from "react-apexcharts"

const Chart = () => {
    const xList = ['ABC-001', 'ABC-002', 'ABC-003', 'ABC-004', 'ABC-005']
    const yList = [20.3, 20.1, 30.6, 10.5, 40.2]

    const chartSeries = [
        {
            name: "Fuel Usage",
            data: yList
        }
    ]

    const chartOptions = {
        chart: { toolbar: "false" },
        dataLabels: { enabled: !1 },
        stroke: { curve: "smooth", width: 2 },
        markers: { size: 0, style: "hollow" },
        xaxis: {
            categories: xList
        },
        tooltip: {
            custom: function({series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w}) {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <p>{series[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]}</p>
                    </div>
                )
            },
            // x: {
            //     show: false
            // }
        },
        colors: ["#4D96F5"],
        fill: {
            type: "gradient",
            gradient: {
                shadeIntensity: 1,
                opacityFrom: 0.4,
                opacityTo: 0.05,
                stops: [50, 100, 100, 100],
            },
        },
    }

    return(
        <ReactApexChart
            options={chartOptions}
            series={chartSeries}
            type="area"
            height={400}
        />
    )
}

export default Chart
```

Environment versions:

```
react-apexcharts: 1.3.7
react: 17.0.2
npm: 6.14.8
node: 12.19.0
```

##### Update

I have implemented HTML string inside tooltip property like this one:

```js
tooltip: {
    custom: function({series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w}) {
        return 
            '<div>' +
                '<span>' + 'Device Name: ' + xList[dataPointIndex] + '</span>' +
                '<span>' + 'Fuel Usage: ' + series[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex] + '</span>' +
            '</div>'
        
    },
    // x: {
    //     show: false
    // }
},
```

but I faced a different result (the tooltip returns `undefined`) as seen in the picture below:

[image: undefined]

You can play with the code here https://codesandbox.io/s/apexchart-rfin2

Comment: can you please share fiddle?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have the fiddle but you can copy and paste all the source code above into a fiddle.

Comment: share your code in some fiddle or snippet so we cn look into it.

Comment: here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/apexchart-rfin2

Answer (score 1):

Your custom tooltip function is returning JSX, which Babel turns into a React component (in turn a JavaScript object). As per the Apex [custom tooltip docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/tooltip/#custom) the function should return a HTML string, so try changing it to:

```
tooltip: {
        custom: function({series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w}) {
            return (
                '<div>' +
                    '<p>' + series[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex] + '</p>' +
                '</div>'
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting.
I have already implemented using HTML string but also failed.
I will update the question soon.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your tooltip function with below code. you are getting an **[object, object]** because this tooltip function is not A JSX element.

```
 tooltip: {
      custom: function ({ series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
        debugger;
        let data=` <div>
        <p>${series[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]}</p>
      </div>`
        return (data);
      }
      // x: {
      //     show: false
      // }
    },
```

here is a working [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/apexchart-forked-ohrqz?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So how to remove/hide the tooltip in the x-axis (as shown in the orange arrow in the bottom of the image above)?

Answer (score 0):

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
    
tooltip: {
  custom: () => ReactDomServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<ATooltipOfYourOwn />) 
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 